# add read more button to woocommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a read more button to WooCommerce products that will be displayed on the product list page under each product and link to the product details page.

How can I do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the content-product.php file in your WooCommerce theme's folder. This file is responsible for displaying each product on the product list page.

```
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

and readmore button

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="woocommerce-loop-product__link">
    <?php _e( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
</a>
```